Why do I get CORS error when server is down?
I have my backend for a project in Node.js which is deployed on AWS EC2 instance it works correctly on all the APIs, but when the server is down due to any reason, a CORS error gets reflected on the client side Networks Tab in Inspect.
I don't know why we are getting CORS error, on my local when the server is not up and I run the frontend app, it gives (failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error which is correct since the server is not up. So, why am I getting  CORS Missing Allow Origin on Prod environment when the server is down.
I expect that when the server is down in Prod environment the client side should get message like Server is Down or any custom message in the Networks Tab of inspect instead of CORS Missing Allow Origin error.
Any solution or suggestion is appreciated.

if you're using fetch in your client, then that will actually throw an exception when the server is down. You should wrap that call in a try-catch, and also check the response for the .ok flag:
try {
  const response = await fetch('/foo')
  if (response.ok) {
    // sucess
  } else {
    // server return 4xx or 5xx status code
  }
} catch (e) {
  // network error or server down
}

The warnings you see in the dev tools are a bit misleading in this case, they're just telling you that the OPTIONS request that checks for CORS failed for some reason.

I tried using try-catch block but it doesn't handle the Network Tab status during Inspect, I want to configure the settings such that in the Networks Tab it should not display CORS error.

@NihalGupta that makes little sense, how a CORS request works is that the browser / client sends an OPTIONS request before sending the actual request, the server is supposed to respond with certain headers, when you don't get a response with those that's automatically a CORS error thats just how the browser works.

@AbdulAzizBarkat It makes sense, but on local when I keep the server off and try to make an api request from browser the OPTIONS request is sent and then the actual but it gives (failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED instead of CORS which is correct. But on Prod the client is getting CORS which should not happen.

@NihalGupta it's possible your browser emits different warnings to the dev console for a localhost url. Or perhaps you have different filters enabled. You don't say which browser you're using. But either way, there's nothing you can do about it, except perhaps switching browsers.
